# React event handler function working without the use of bind()

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and I came across event handlers. In React, it is recommended to bind the function to `this`, before using it as an event handler. However, I did not bind it and I am still getting the desired output. Below is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Experiment extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

    }

    clickEvent(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById('change').innerHTML="This text changed";
        }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <p id='change'>This paragraph will change</p>
                <button onClick={this.clickEvent}>Press me</button>
            </div>
            );
    }
}

export default Experiment;
```

As you can see, I haven't bound `clickEvent()` to `this`, yet the `onClick` event works without a hitch. Why is that? I assumed that I would have gotten an `undefined` error or something else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this works is because you aren't referring to anything using 'this' within your clickEvent function.
Within javascript, the 'this' variable within a function refers to the object that the function was called from.

To prove this, try accessing `this.props` or `this.state`, they will return undefined because you are missing your `.bind(this)`

.bind() will return a new function, that will stick with a given 'this' context, no matter where it is called from.

```
const myObj = {
    name: 'John',
    testFunction: function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
};

const testFunction = myObj.testFunction;

myObj.testFunction(); // John
testFunction(); // undefined


const testFunctionBound = testFunction.bind(myObj);
testFunctionBound(); // John
```

Comment: I love it @Jye. Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

*As a theoretical sidenote to Jye Lewis answer above, and clarifications on the subject.*

There are 3 regular ways of binding context to functions in react:

1. *Bind (usually in constructor)*
2. *Class field/property with arrow*
3. *Arrow in render*

*example code:*

```
class ThisDemo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 

    // 1. In constructor 
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  // 2. Class field/property with arrow
  onClick = () => {  
  }

  render() {
    // 3. Arrow in render
    return (
      <button type="button" onClick={event => console.log(event)}>
        Pretty Button
      </button>
    ); 
  }
}
export default ThisDemo;
```

### Ups and downs

1. *Bind (usually in constructor)*

   - **ups:** On same protetype no matter how big N is.
   - **downs:** Polluting the constructor
2. *Class field/property with arrow*

   - **ups:** Very convenient , nice syntax. For N components create N different functions.
   - **downs:** In some cases, loss of performance. *(N high)*
3. *Arrow in render*

   - **ups:** Can catch events in a simple way, good for performing logic without passing down props for callback parameters.
   - **downs:** You are passing a new inline arrow function with every render. Always a new reference, which could cause re-rendering.

### Wisdoms

You should only bind with.bind() or arrow function if you're going to pass the function around.

Class field/property with arrow is convenient but could be inefficient if many `This.Demo` components

Be *pragmatic* until you can't be. The performance issues are almost never a problem, and they might change how it works in the future.

### Reference

1. [This article](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1) helped me alot in understanding the different methods.
2. Also [this one](https://medium.com/@pauloesteves8/es6-classes-binding-public-class-fields-and-event-handling-in-react-2e1e39b1d498).

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrow functions instead of creating constructor and calling both `super` and

`bind`  methods.

> An arrow function does not have its own this, but it has the this
>   value of the enclosing execution context. Arrow Functions lexically
>   bind their context so this actually refers to the originating context.
>   That’s called Lexical Scoping if you’re into naming things. Basically,
>   it saves us from doing .bind(this) in our code. Note that this is an
>   experimental feature in JS, which means it’s not yet accepted into
>   ECMAScript standard

So, instead of doing this way:

```
//with binding in a constructor and calling super method
class Experiment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 

    // 1. In constructor 
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }
...
}
```

You can do it in a cleaner way like below:

```
  //with arrow 
  handleOnClick = product => {  
     ...
  }
```

And in your `render` method you do something like:

```
class Experiment extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={ () => this.handleOnClick(product) } >
            Add new product
        </button>
    );
  }
}
```

[Read more about arrow functions in this article:](https://medium.com/@nikolalsvk/loosing-bind-this-in-react-8637ebf372cf)